# Change text by tap a button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I writing android app and have TextView, where I have number of products and imagebuttons "+" and "-".

I want to change number of products by tapping it

I realized this:

```
ImageButton minus = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.minus);

        ImageButton plus = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.plus);
plus.Click += delegate
        {
            counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", count++);
        };  
        minus.Click += delegate
        {
            counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", --count);
        };
```

But when I tap "+" it changes number from 1 to 2 for example, and after this "-" does nothing when I tap it. If I tap it twice, my number changed from 2 to 1.

What problem, why it doesn't change when I tap first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x++ and x-- are postfix operators - they return the value of x, and then increment/decrement it.

++x and --x are prefix operators - they increment/decrement the value of x, then return the value.

You are using a postfix operator in one case and a prefix operator in the other, so you are getting inconsistent results.  You probably want to use the prefix operator in both cases.

Comment: Thanks so much. It helped me